# Assign an icon for each category

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to assign an icon for each category. On my home page, I want to list 12 random categories from the database but I also want to return a specific icon for each one. My idea is to assign a unique `class name` for each link, something like `category_{name of the category}` and return the icon with `::before` style. But in my opinion there must be a better way of doing it since `::before` doesn't work everywhere.

I did some research but have not found anything specific. Can someone give an advice or example please? Thank you for your help and time.

Here is an example what I want to do:
[image]

My `for_loop`:

```
- @books.each do |b|
  .col-xs-2
    = link_to book_path(b), class: "c-link--block" do
      .c-card__book
        .c-card__book__cover(style="background-image: url('#{b.avatar}')")
          .c-card__book__header
            %h5(class="c-heading--4") #{b.name}
            %p(class="c-text--3") #{b.subcategory.name}
```

Comment: Ca't you just make teh image the background of the element with the desired class, and pad all of the text out accordingly?

Comment: @BradWerth hm... i've never though about it. Will try to do it this way, thank you.

Comment: can you show some of the code, it's kinda hard to answer this. you could just save a icon_url attribute for each category annd add that to the html.

Comment: @maxpleaner I updated my question with the `for loop` that I use